# How to draw line by scratching on map using OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, openlayers

Is it possible to draw line by scratching on the map using OpenLayers? I tried some examples, all the examples are drawing by clicking. I want to draw by scratching, just like drawing in normal life on the paper. Is it possible to implement by OpenLayers?

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/draw-feature.html Choose draw line and scratch while maintaining SHIFT key pressed.